# Excel: filtering text to show rows with certain words AND without certain words

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have a table with 3 columns:

[image: Table with 3 columns]

I want to filter to only show rows that contain an animal from the animal field, but not a place name in the city field.

In this example, I want to only return row 2, because chicken is in column C, but dallas is not in column B.

From what I've read it seems like I may need to use a COUNTIF in a new column(s) and then filter based on the 0/1. But I'm struggling to get it working properly if the column is not an exact match. I need it to still pick up the row if it was "dallas in Chicken" for example (case and order insensitive).

Would including wildcards on either side of each entry in columns B and C help?

I'd prefer not to use Access if possible as I need to manipulate the data further in Excel.

Comment: Function `FIND()` will return the position of city/animal in a cell, and `#VALUE!` if it abcent. Using `IF(ISERROR()...` convert this position to 1 when animal found and 0 otherwise, and backward for the city. Filter by the sum of this two `IF(ISERROR()...` is 2.

Comment: @Akina not sure if that will work because =FIND() requires me to put in a specific cell rather than a range. I need to be able to check if the cell has any of multiple animals (and there could be thousands of animals).

Comment: @user16421,,, as row 2 what you want the Formula to return only Value from `A2` or the entire `Row 2` (A2+B2+C2) ?

Comment: Use SUMIF() over each tested value, summarising IF(expression=2,1,0), filter the rows which gives non-zero value.

Comment: @Akina,, y don't you post an answer instead of Comments !!

Comment: @RajeshS just the value from A2.

Comment: @RajeshS It seems to be simple enough, and I'm too lazy to build complete solution. Comment seems to be enough... maybe somebody else will do it using my comment?

Comment: @Akina I don't quite understand, sorry. Would that still involve checking each animal against each value in column A? If so, I want to avoid that if possible as there are thousands of animals, cities, and strings. Might be misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: @Akina,,, now let me try then ☺

Answer (score 0):

**Helper Column solves the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `D31` to find the partial match.

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH(C$31:C$34,A31),C$31:C$34),"No Match")`

**N.B.** `Lookup(1E+100,,` find the largest match value wrapped with `SEARCH`, as a Lookup value input, then it searches for the first value in the Lookup Array from right to left and it ignores text, errors and blanks cells.

- Final Formula in Cell `E31` to pull the Row (*Column A Value*) for the partial match with Animal name.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D31&"*",$A$31:$C$34,1,FALSE),"")`

## Edited:

- In case of resembling words like `Chick`, `ick` or `Ick`, Formula in `E31` needs little modification.

  ```
   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D31&" *",$A$31:$C$35,1,FALSE),"")
  ```
- SPACE before `*` sign,, `(VLOOKUP($D31&" *",`.

[image]

- Fill Formulas Down.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.

Comment: Thanks for that. The one issue I can see is it's not treating it as full words. For example, if I put "Chick" or "ick" as one of the animals, replacing "Chicken", this would still return "Chicken in Dallas" in column E.

Comment: @user16421,, now check the Edited part ,, your issue with `Click` & `ick` has been solved!!